# Apache Spark and Domain Driven Design

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I've got somewhat of an abstract question. I've been using Apache Spark (also Streaming and SQL) with Scala quite a lot lately. Most of my Spark jobs basically move RDDs/Dataframes from one class to another where each class performs some transformations on the input.

I've also been reading about Domain Driven Design lately which made me think about how I would model my Spark programs using DDD. I got to say I'm finding it much harder to model Spark code than non Spark code using DDD concepts (maybe its because it mostly performs transformations or IO). I can probably think about how to create a ubiquitous language but not how to actually apply it in the Spark code itself.

I tried googling how to use Spark with DDD but couldn't find anything about it and so I was wondering:

- Am I just missing something on how to apply the DDD concepts on Spark code?
- Maybe Spark jobs are so focused on ETLs that they don't actually require any use of DDD? If that's not the case could someone explain how she/he is using DDD concepts with Spark code? Maybe some examples could be useful

I hope this is a legitimate question - if not, I apologize

Thanks in advance

Comment: Spark is intended for short-running, rather simple but memory/computation demanding jobs . DDD is something you use  for modelling rather complex systems - so the typical setup is to have spark project somewhere on the side processing your data and persisting it in aggregated form,  and DDD project that actually uses processed data.

Comment: These simple computations can sometimes turn into rather big systems with quite a lot of  code - Don't you think that when they become quite a complex system with lots of lines of code and classes they also require to be re-modeled?

Answer (score 0):

Spark's DSL and DDD are vastly different abstractions. The challenge you have stems from the "distance" between the two abstractions. This is a common problem in complex system design and it indicates that there is a missing abstraction to bridge the two. In your case, that would be an abstraction that fits well with DDD and then "generates" Spark transformations via the DSL. Scala is well-suited to building such an abstraction. For a hint of what is possible, see: https://databricks.com/session/the-smart-data-warehouse-goal-based-data-production